# Undefined index notice error when trying to add a new user role in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, user-roles, admin-user

I am getting a error "Undefined index: title in \vendor\magento\module-integration\Helper\Data.php on line 24" in magento 2 when trying to add a new user role. please help me

Comment: Solved the error: It is because of the custom module acl.xml file error ,the title tag is not specified there.